# How to remove underscores using angularjs in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I am working on already developed code in AngularJS with Rails.

I am having a code which prints all the workflow states like `not_found, in_process, new` etc;

```
<td>
  <div class="editable-wrapper">
    <a e-name="states" e-ng-options="s.id as s.name for s in workflowStates" editable-select="address.workflowState" onbeforesave="updateAddress({workflowState: $data}, address)">{{ address.workflowState | capitalise }}</a>
  </div>
</td>
```

Now with the above code `{{ address.workflowState | capitalise }}`, the page is showing as In_process, New etc;

My aim is to remove the underscores and display them as `In process/ in process`, `Not found / not found` etc. (Capitalize is not essential but have to remove underscore).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a filter and use like:

**HTML:**

```
<a e-name="states" e-ng-options="s.id as s.name for s in workflowStates" editable-select="address.workflowState" onbeforesave="updateAddress({workflowState: $data}, address)">{{address.workflowState | removeUnderscores}}</a>
```

**Filter:**

```
filterExample.filter('removeUnderscores', function () {
        return function (text) {
            var str = text.replace(/_/g, ' ');
            return str
        };
})
```

[**DEMO FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5WnTA/207/)

Here's a **One Liner**

```
<a e-name="states" e-ng-options="s.id as s.name for s in workflowStates" editable-select="address.workflowState" onbeforesave="updateAddress({workflowState: $data}, address)">{{address.workflowState.split("_").join(" ")}}</a>
```

**[DEMO FIDDLE FOR ONE LINER](http://jsfiddle.net/5WnTA/211/)**

Comment: @venkat: Added one liner.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this filter](https://github.com/Puigcerber/angular-capitalize-filter) (Disclaimer: I'm the author) that does exactly what you need.

```
{{ address.workflowState | capitalize:'first':'_' }}
```

If you want to implement it by yourself it could be something like this:

```
angular.module('angular-capitalize-filter',[])
  .filter('capitalize', function () {
    return function (input) {
      if (!input) {
        return input;
      }
      // Capitalize the first letter of a sentence
      var output = input.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + input.slice(1).toLowerCase();
      return output.split('_').join(' ');
    }
});
```

And then use it as:

```
{{ address.workflowState | capitalize }}
```

Comment: Hi thanks. `{{ address.workflowState | capitalize:'first':'_' }}` looks cool. If i am having something like **no_charge_approved**, then how can we use ?

Comment: The `first` mean you capitalize just the first word so it would look like **No charge approved** but if you want to capitalize all the words you can use `all` and it will look like **No Charge Approved**.

Comment: I used `{{ address.workflowState | capitalise:'all':'_'}}`, it is working when i refresh the page. Is there anyway to add refresh or anything?

Comment: It should work out of the box without the need to refresh the page. How are you loading your data? Do you think you can put your code in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Any one line answer please like capitalise... Or can we use humanise?

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your code it's impossible to help. By your markup I understand you are using **Angular-xeditable** which I've tried with the **capitalize** filter and works. So the problem might be somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own filter for replacing `_` with `space` as bellow

```
angular.module('your-module-name', [])
    .filter('stateformat', function() {
        return function(input) {
            if(input != null && input.length > 0)
            return input.replace('_', ' ');
        }
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<td>
  <div class="editable-wrapper">
    <a e-name="states" e-ng-options="s.id as s.name for s in workflowStates" editable-select="address.workflowState" onbeforesave="updateAddress({workflowState: $data}, address)">{{ address.workflowState | capitalise | stateformat }}</a>
  </div>
</td>
```